# How much noise should I add to my training data to test model robustness

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, supervised-learning, robust

For research purposes I am performing a regression prediction task which involves two time series (A and B).  Aim was to map input: time series A and the last value seen in time series B into the value for the next step in time series B. The prediction task was successful outperforming the baseline (persistence algorithm) nicely. Algorithms used are KNN, Decision Tree, Random Forest and SVM (regressors).

However, I need to include robustness of the models in the research.  From what I understand robustness relates to the extent to which the models fit noise. Being more robust is the ability of a model to fit noise to a lesser extent. I would like to test the robustness of the models by adding noise to my training data.

```r
    x <- runif(100, 100, 150)  # (this is the original training data 
                               # which I'm just making up)

    corrupt <- rbinom(length(x), 1, 0.1)    # (choose an average of 
                            # for example 10% to corrupt at random)
    corrupt <- as.logical(corrupt)
    noise <- rnorm(sum(corrupt), 1000, 200) # (generate the noise to 
                                            # add)
    x[corrupt] <- x[corrupt] + noise      # (about 10% of x has been 
                                          # corrupted)
```

If I want to test robustness via adding noise, what percentages relate to minor, moderate or a lot of noise added to the training data?

Comment: Interesting question!, Have you got a clear idea where you would add noise (training or testing data)?. Because I have the same concern.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is no precise answer . I would just try increasing the error variance until tests of significance for model parameters are no longer significant given the estimated level of variability in the model errors. You might also consider introducing deterministic effects like pulses , seasonal pulse , level shifts ,local time trends to inject "enhanced variance".

Comment: Another feature worth considering would be big shocks, the occasional gigantic outlier. This could be especially useful if what you’re doing is financial.

Comment: The gigantic outlier is really a gigantic pulse.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to estimate the real life noise you have in your data. You may have an idea, what kind of noise is expected.

One way to evaluate the robustness may be to add noise to the training set, train again, and see how much the model has changed. But I do not see how you can use it.

Another way is to train a model on the training set, then test it on the training set with added noise. Then, you evaluate model robustness by the changes in its performance. I think, this may give you better idea of what you may get on the test data.